# How to multiply all rows in a column by 3?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

For example, I have 10, 20 and 30 in a column then i want all of them to be multiplied by 3.

```
con.Open()
cmd.CommandText = " select * from pawns where item_no = '" & txtID.Text & "' and second_date <= NOW(); "
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

If dr.HasRows Then
    dr.Read()
    b = dr.Item("total_amount") * 3     
    dr.Close()
End If
```

Comment: Start by turning on Option Strict, then use SQL params instead of string concat to build SQL then explain how that approach doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the SQL as shown below in the sample code where a assumption is made there are no null values. All code has Option Strict On and uses xml literals to create the sql statement.

NOTE: This is done with SQL-Server but the same applied for all databases via a managed .NET data provider.

```
Dim SearchValue As Integer = 12
' create nicely formatted statement with xml literals
Dim SelectStatement As String =
    <SQL>
        SELECT 
            ID, 
            item_no, 
            total_amount, 
            ItemDescription, 
            ([total_amount]*3) AS Total 
        FROM Table1 
            WHERE item_no = @ItemIdentifier));                
    </SQL>.Value

Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "TODO"}
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = SelectStatement}

        ' strong type parameter optionally use AddWithValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter With
                           {
                               .ParameterName = "@ItemIdentifier",
                               .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                               .Value = SearchValue
                           }
                       )

        cn.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows Then

            While reader.Read
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0} Total: {1}",
                                  reader.GetString(3),
                                  reader.GetInt32(4))
            End While

            reader.Close()
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

SQL can be done as follows too

```
Dim SelectStatement As String =
    "SELECT ID, item_no, total_amount, ItemDescription, (total_amount * 3) AS Total " &
    "FROM Table1  WHERE item_no = @ItemIdentifier));"
```

It is ill advised to use SELECT * for selecting data, always specify the fields you need instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that SqlDataReader.Item returns an object, not a number.  Your poor code doesn't know, at this point, if `dr.Item("total_amount")` is going to return a string, a byte array, an integer, a date ...  It's waiting -- with bated breath -- for you to ... err ... tell it.

So ... just tell it:

b = CType(dr.Item("total_amount"), Double) * 3

Unless total_amount is a nullable bigint value ... Then, you'd have more work to do.

```
If IsDBNull(dr.Item("total_value")) Then
    Return 0;
Else
    Return CType(dr.Item("total_value"), long)
End If
```

Of course, at this point .. you are so close to an extension method you can almost smell it!  Wouldn't it be easier if you could just call `dr.GetOrDefault(of long)("total_value",0)` ...  Yeah.  That'd be cool.  Like ... dr.GetSqlInt64(0), but with the column name...

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Function GetOrDefault(Of T)(dr As SqlDataReader, name As String, [default] As T) As T
    If IsDBNull(dr.Item(name)) Then
        Return [default]
    Else
        Return CType(dr.Item(name), T)
    End If
End Function
```

Yeah.  That'd be cool.  You should write something like that.  It'd save SO much code-time.